# Comtypes.client usages under Windows 8.1 failed

Tags: python, windows-8.1, comtypes

I have been using the comtypes package for a Photoshop automation for a long time. This is my old version-combination:

```
WindowsXP/Python 2.4/ctypes/comtypes 0.6.2/Photoshop CS4
```

After I have moved to Windows 8.1 in combination with Photoshop CS6 I am not able to move my scripts to the new enviroment.

Using Python 2.4

*psApp = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')*

causes a `SyntaxError`. Then I updated to Python 2.7.8. Here I am not able to install comtypes 1.1.1

Can you please explain what versions of Python & comtypes do I need for a Photoshop CS6 automation under Windows 8.1 and how to install the comtypes package?

Thanks in advance!